# Unity: How can I programmatically solve an animated sprite with multiple colliders causing scoring issues?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have an animated sprite which has 8 frames of animation. Each frame has a PolygonCollider2D attached as an element of an array thus providing it with accurate collision detection no matter which frame is playing.

When I had only one collider on the sprite and it passed through the "score" object the player's score increased by 1 point.

```
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Point")
    {
        score++;
        scoreText.text = score.ToString();
        return;
    }
}
```

[Polygon Collider 2D array in Unity inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bsy5j.jpg)

Each collider in the array becomes active in turn...

```
public void SetColliderForSprite(int spriteNum)
{
    colliders[batColliderIndex].enabled = false;
    batColliderIndex = spriteNum;
    colliders[batColliderIndex].enabled = true;
}
```

Now that each frame of the animation has its own collider I find that the score is increasing at an alarming rate as each frame plays multiple times whilst inside the "score" game object, triggering the point scoring logic multiple times, before the player leaves said object.

I'm wondering what the ideal programmatic solution is in order to ensure that on entering the "point" collider object the player only gets a score increment once before exiting the area?

Thanks in advance for any suggestions (and my apologies if this has been answered elsewhere).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: I was thinking about my post below and I think there is a simpler solution. You should be able to animate your collider shape rather than having 1 collider per animation frame. For example, see this question on [How to update 2d colliders with sprite animation](https://answers.unity.com/questions/1204815/how-to-update-2d-colliders-with-spirte-animation.html).

(And as a side note, you can also have multiple polygon colliders on each part of the sprite, and animate the colliders to move accordingly. For example, see this post on [Animating Polygon Collider 2D](https://forum.unity.com/threads/animating-polygon-collider-2d.435019/). This alternative approach might make the suggestion I make in my post below simpler.)

---

One suggestion I have is to only increment the score when the first `"Point"` trigger is detected and then not incrementing the score again until the object has fully left. This can be implemented by keeping track of how many colliders (or which specific colliders) have entered and exited the object. Something like the following:

```
private const string PointTag = "Point";
private int _triggerCount;

private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == PointTag)
    {
        bool firstCollision = (_triggerCount == 0);

        if (firstCollision)
        {
            score++;
            scoreText.text = score.ToString();
        }

        _triggerCount++;
    }
}

private void OnTriggerExit2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == PointTag)
    {
        _triggerCount--;
    }
}
```

However, once a collision is in progress, you will likely have to change the behaviour so that all colliders stay active until the object has fully left the collision area. This is because if you disable the collider, the `OnTriggerExit2D` event will not fire.

This solution may not be acceptable depending on how accurately you need to detect that the `VampireBat` has left the collision area.

If it doesn't need to be very accurate, you can simplify the solution by adding a 9th collider with a unique tag that covers the entire area of the sprite's animation. By using this 9th collider to determine when the player has left the collision area, you would not need to worry about affecting the code related to showing the appropriate collider per animation frame. (But note that the code example here would have to be modified so that the `OnTriggerExit2D` uses this 9th collider object.)

If it needs to be more accurate, I think there is likely a solution similar to what I suggested based on which colliders are currently active, the details of your collider shapes & animation frames, and `OnTrigerEnter2D`, `OnTriggerStay`, and `OnTriggerExit2D`. But note that you may also need to be careful that a collision is not re-triggered immediately. (For example, the object may have fully left the collision area, but the next animation frame might trigger a collision again immediately.)

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the response. Your edit got me to thinking about child objects. I added a child collider (with an index value of 9) then checked for a collision with that.

[child object in inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kGISl.jpg)

Referenced the child collider in the collider array.

[Collider array in inspector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uTpij.jpg)

After that it was just a matter of referencing it in the player controller script.

```
// Update is called once per frame
void Update () {
    //Player input
    if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
    {
        bat.velocity = new Vector2(0, 4);
        //ADD BAT FLAP SOUND LATER!!!

    }
    scoreText.text = score.ToString();
    Debug.Log("SCORE: " + score);
}

//Point increment function
private void OnTriggerEnter2D(Collider2D collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Point" && batColliderIndex == 9)
    {
        score++;
        return;
    }
}
```

I now have pixel perfect collision detection against obstacles and a score which increments correctly.

Thanks again.

Comment: Glad I could help! Please accept or upvote my answer if it helped you.